# Entity Framework Core Add-Migration throws "An item with the same key has already been added. Key: MyProject.Model.MyContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I have a SQL Server Database with EF Core in my project and I want to add a table and a column in another table. But when I run `Add-Migration` in the PM Console I get this Error

`An item with the same key has already been added. Key: MyProject.Model.MyContext`

where `MyProject`is my asp.net core project and `MyContext`is my DbContext class.

My DbContext class looks like

```
namespace MyProject.Model
{
    public class MyContext : DbContext
    {
        public MyWorker Worker { get; private set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// initialize the worker instance to get the crud methods of the database
        /// </summary>
        public MyContext()
        {
            Worker = new MyWorker(this);
        }

        public static string GetConnectionString()
        {
            return Startup.ConnectionString;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Our own context must override the OnConfiguring Method from Ef Core to set the right connection
        /// Connectionstring is set in appsettings.json
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="_builder"></param>
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder _builder)
        {
            _builder.UseSqlServer(GetConnectionString());
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder _modelBuilder)        {
            _modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasIndex(u => u.MailAdress).IsUnique();
        }

        public DbSet<Project>  Projects  { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Document> Documents { get; set; }
        public DbSet<DocData>  DocsData  { get; set; }
        public DbSet<User>     Users     { get; set; }
        public DbSet<UCLSystem>   Systems   { get; set; }
    }


    public class DesignTimeContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<MyContext>
    {
        public MyContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
        {
            IConfiguration configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                .Build();

            var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyContext>();

            var connectionString = configuration["Connectionstrings:MyConnection"];

            return new MyContext();
        }
    }
}
```

The table to add is the `Systems` Table and the two columns to add are in the `documents` table.

With the `-verbose` flag I get the following output

```
PM> Add-Migration Update -verbose
Using project 'MyProject'.
Using startup project 'MyProject'.
Build started...
Build succeeded.
C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe exec --depsfile D:\Development\Project\MyProject\MyProject\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.2\MyProject.deps.json --additionalprobingpath C:\Users\chris\.nuget\packages --additionalprobingpath "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder" --runtimeconfig D:\Development\Project\MyProject\MyProject\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.2\MyProject.runtimeconfig.json C:\Users\chris\.nuget\packages\microsoft.entityframeworkcore.tools\2.2.4\tools\netcoreapp2.0\any\ef.dll migrations add Update --json --verbose --no-color --prefix-output --assembly D:\Development\Project\MyProject\MyProject\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.2\MyProject.dll --startup-assembly D:\Development\Project\MyProject\MyProject\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.2\MyProject.dll --project-dir D:\Development\Project\MyProject\MyProject\ --language C# --working-dir D:\Development\Project\MyProject --root-namespace MyProject
Using assembly 'MyProject'.
Using startup assembly 'MyProject'.
Using application base 'D:\Development\Project\MyProject\MyProject\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.2'.
Using working directory 'D:\Development\Project\MyProject\MyProject'.
Using root namespace 'MyProject'.
Using project directory 'D:\Development\Project\MyProject\MyProject\'.
Finding DbContext classes...
Finding IDesignTimeDbContextFactory implementations...
Found IDesignTimeDbContextFactory implementation 'DesignTimeContextFactory'.
Found DbContext 'MyContext'.
Found IDesignTimeDbContextFactory implementation 'DesignTimeContextFactory'.
Found DbContext 'MyContext'.
System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added. Key: MyProject.Model.MyContext
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.TryInsert(TKey key, TValue value, InsertionBehavior behavior)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.FindContextTypes()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.FindContextType(String name)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.AddMigration(String name, String outputDir, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigrationImpl(String name, String outputDir, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
An item with the same key has already been added. Key: MyProject.Model.MyContext
```

Comment: Could you share the structure of the Entities?

Comment: There is usually more information about the specific issue in the EF migration error; can you take a look and post it?  There is also a -Verbose flag you can supply to the command.

Comment: Edit the Question with the output

Comment: It looks likes it's found the actual context `MyContext` twice; perhaps you know from your refactoring where to look for that.  Also try explicitly clean out all the obj and bin folders for the solution and then rebuilding.

Comment: Get the same error after deleting these folders an rebuild the project.

Comment: Are you sure you only have one `DesignTimeContextFactory` in the whole solution?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. But I have another IConfiguration in the startup.cs and I'm not sure if this is a problem.

Comment: It finds factories by scanning the "startup" assembly for anything that implements `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<DbContext>`.  Try adding this to your `MyProject`, as near to the startup as you can, set a debugger breakpoint, run (the app) and inspect the results to see whether you get one or 2 values:
`IEnumerable<TypeInfo> contextFactories = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().DefinedTypes.Where(t => !t.IsAbstract && !t.IsGenericTypeDefinition).Where(t => typeof(IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<DbContext>).GetTypeInfo().IsAssignableFrom(t));`

Comment: Under the point Results View is only one, my DesignTimeContextFactory.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193401/discussion-between-sellotape-and-pospich0815).

Answer (score 8):

In my case, I needed to delete the generated snapshot CS file and re-generate the migration.

Comment: This will not create the desired migration. The migration uses the snapshot as a basis for creating the needed changes. Starting from an empty snapshot will generate a migration that recreates all tables that were not deleted.

Answer (score 8):

This error often occur when you are trying to drop a table which has multiple/duplicate foreign keys to/for a single table.

Therefore firstly you have to drop foreign keys in single migration. After that drop the table.